# Understanding Rashi: sparing Moabites because of Ruth?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pinchas

> מאת המדינים. וְלֹא מֵאֵת הַמּוֹאָבִים, ... מִפְּנֵי שְׁנֵי פְרֵידוֹת טוֹבוֹת שֶׁיֵּשׁ לִי לְהוֹצִיא מֵהֶם —
>   רוּת הַמּוֹאֲבִיָּה וְנַעֲמָה הָעַמּוֹנִית ([Rashi Num 31,2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.31.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

Why would G-d spare punishing the whole wicked nation if He could miraculously save Ruth and Naama's ascendants?

Comment: Maybe the fact that Ruth would not only be of Moabite descent, but also would grow in Moabite culture, yet become the exemplar _Gerat Tzedeq_ she was, is enough to merit Moab (as a nation) being spared.

Comment: Dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84050/

Comment: @DonielF Wow, it probably is, but yours was so long and exhausting, also the title is so general, only the final question is about Ruth and Naamah.